# How do you get a facebook user's information and insert it into a database?

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I wasn't sure how to ask it, but I am trying to teach myself how to create a program that uses the graph api.  Most of the tutorials I have seen are older, and I don't know how relevant they are now.  Essentially, I am trying to get the "thing" where someons clicks my app, it says, this app wants your username, etc. and then Allow or Don't Allow.

I want it to take the information and then I can insert it into a database.  I am using php and have a domain.

I can insert the data no problem, if I can get the data.  I don't understand how to do it.

I'm sorry for a vague question, and I have searched.  Not asking you to write my code for me, just point me in the right direction, maybe to a modern tutorial doing what I am asking.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked in the facebook php sdk examples?

Comment: I don't think I know where to look.  I only saw the graph api, but couldn't tell what to do.

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**1)** Create a Facebook application from here:

http://developers.facebook.com/apps

And configure it with your domain.

This step is really easy, put any namespace you want that will be your application name, then check that your application will be used as an "application and login page" (not a fan page or something related) and finally specify the URLs where you will use Facebook API (leave Canvas URL blank).

Just a heads up, I believe Facebook API requires HTTPS URLs but I don't know why is still allowing HTTP, so don't worry by now.

**Login config:**

Set the URL: http://yourdomain.com/

**Application config:**

http://yourdomain.com/myfacebookapp/

So, when a user goes to:

http://apps.facebook.com/yourappName

Means that a user is really browsing the first link and in that page (let's say `index.php`) you will need to do everything from below.

Just FYI, at this point you can also set a logo for your application, manage administrators and get your application ID and secret that you will use in your PHP file later.

*(If you get confused in this step you can do a Google search, this configuration is easy to find)*

**2)** I always use these files to link my PHP enviroment with Facebook API, here's the link from my Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/itw4pav1f7a9vez/files.rar

**3)** Put those files in a folder called `fb`.

**4)** I will show you the way to get data and picture from a user but first the user has to allow your application to get this info when getting logged in your application.

So, for this example I will use a simple button for the login:

*(Don't forget to replace your application ID and secret, notice the 'xxx' and 'yyy')*

```
<?php

require 'fb/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxx',
  'secret' => 'yyy',
));

// Check if user is already logged
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Get login or logout URL
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}

?>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>Facebook PHP SDK</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Facebook PHP SDK</h1>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
    <?php else: ?>
      <div>
        <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>PHP Session</h3>
    <pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <h3>Your picture</h3>
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">

      <h3>Your info (/me)</h3>
      <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
    <?php else: ?>
      <strong><em>You are not connected.</em></strong>
    <?php endif ?>
</html>
```

**5)** Above example uses Facebook PHP SDK without JavaScript. So, if user wants to login and authorize your application to get the info then the whole page will be redirected to the Facebook permissions page of your application and after it will go back to the main page of your Facebook application (specified in the configurations from your application).

**6)** Below code will do the same as above but using JavaScript and custom Facebook login button that allows you to put special permissions as you wrote in your question. Another difference is that a popup will appear instead of redirecting the whole page.

*(Don't forget to replace your application ID and secret, notice the 'xxx' and 'yyy')*

```
<?php

require 'fb/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxx',
  'secret' => 'yyy',
));

// Check if user is already logged
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $user = null;
  }
} else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}

?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Facebook PHP SDK</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <fb:login-button size="small" onlogin="after_login_button()" scope="email, user_about_me, user_birthday, user_status, publish_stream, user_photos, read_stream, friends_likes">Login with facebook</fb:login-button>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
              appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>',
              cookie: true,
              xfbml: true,
              oauth: true
            });
            
            // This is used by Facebook login button
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
              if (response.authResponse) {
                 // Specify the login page where Facebook login button is located
                 window.location = 'main.php';
              }
            });
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
                window.location = 'logout.php';
            });
          };
          (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script'); 

            e.async = true;
            e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';

            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
          }());
          
          function after_login_button(){
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                if (response.status == 'connected') {
                    // If user is connected, redirect to below page
                    window.location = 'main.php';
                }
            }, true);
          }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**7)** As you can see, the scope attribute in the Facebook login button determines which special permissions and info your application will need from a user like the email for example (which is always private unless authorized).

---

**8)** To add something, you can get only public information from someone by using the following:

```
// For example: Your Facebook friend's profile is http://www.facebook.com/foobar
$myFriend = $facebook->api('/foobar');
// For example: Your Facebook friend's profile is http://www.facebook.com/users/1002020300010
$myFriend = $facebook->api('/1002020300010');
// Print the name
echo $myFriend['name'];
// Print all data
print_r($myFriend);
```

And, in order to get your Facebook friend's picture just do this:

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/foobar/picture">
```

Or:

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/1002020300010/picture">
```

---

**Finally, supposing that you have all user info that was needed then now you can save it all into DB without problems or restrictions.**

Hope this helps as reference.

Comment: Hi! I've read your answer and I have to thank you because it has been very learning for me. My problem is that my app doesn't recognize the user logged in. My question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646494/facebook-login-window-appears-and-disappears-very-quickly. I've tried the second code you have posted and it doesn't worked. I mean, I can log in but I can't log out after loggin in. Would you know why is it happening? Thanks @Oscar Jara

Comment: @oscar Thank you so much for your time.  I'm sure I'll refer back to this many times.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are looking to creating an authentication (login) using Facebook.

You may wish to check out [Opauth](http://opauth.org), it handles all of that for you and returns you the user info in an array, of which you can then insert into database easily.

See http://opauth.org for a quick demo and download the library which contains sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are using the PHP SDK Classes provided by Facebook [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/)

You can do something like this

```
$fb = new Facebook(array(
     'appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
     'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET'
));


$userData = $fb->api('/me','GET');
$userData = serialize($userData);

//now userdata is a string, so, insert into the database.
```

Remembering, in your app configurantion, you must specify the kind of information you want from user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php API and the query language that facebook provides (FQL). Here is a link that contains sample query's and tutorials http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/