# Facebook login window appears and disappears

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am using js sdk to login using `<fb:login-button></fb:login-button>` button

When I click "login"  button on my page, the pop up box appears and disappears quickly.

I found this other thread on here
[Facebook login window appears and disappears very quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646494/facebook-login-window-appears-and-disappears-very-quickly)

Which explains that it happens because the user is already logged into facebook. My question is, how do I go around this issue? 
if they are already logged in to facebook, how do I make sure the pop up doesn't just appear and disappear?

Comment: I don't think there's a work-around - it can be seen quite everywhere. However, I'm thinking of pop-under (will likely aggravate the browser) or a hidden iFrame (unless facebook uses a frame buster, which it likely does)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the user's login status with FB.getLoginStatus.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

If the user is not logged in you could display a (custom) login button.

Answer (score 0):

I want to complement FWrnr's answer with actual code, because this is indeed very helpful.

The solution is the FB.getLoginStatus function as he says:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        window.location = //redirect to page with logged user (you have the response token in response)
    } else {
      //Show the login popup
      FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
          window.location = //redirect to location after correct login
        }
      }, { scope: '<scopes>', state: '<state>' });
    }
  });
```

This way, if the user is "connected" (logged in and app authorised), you won't call the FB.login method, so the login window won't flash. In any other case, it will show the login window, which is the expected result.